# Ionic Cordova on Windows 7 cannot create project

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

Straight to the point, I am trying to learn and play around with Ionic development.

> Installed Node.js

and

> npm install -g cordova ionic

, seems to install successfully , i can see the version. Now when i run the command **ionic start**   , the folder gets created but after that i am getting a message Downloading and extracting  starter after a few seconds it just stops. Then when i cd into the newly created directory i found nothing.

So what i have tried, i uninstalled cleaned and reinstalled node and cordova ionic for around 10 times, searched left and right of google and i am unable to find solution *(Maybe i am not searching properly)* . I am running Windows 7 sp1 ultimate edition, Turned off firewall ,restarted the system a few times . Nothing i am unable to move from this step, any Ideas, I am adding pictures for the reference. 
[image]

[image]

[image: ionic start command with verbose]

any help and pointers will be greatly appreciated. What i am doing wrong ???
this is a home system and i am definitely not behind a proxy.

**[EDIT]**
as per the comment i tried and here is the result

[image]

**EDIT** today once again i retried with ionic now i am seeing different error

[image]

Comment: I suggest two things. 1. Try this in a cmd window with administrative rights. 2. When you cd inside the project dir, type `npm install`

Comment: any comments and suggestions, or i just drop ionic...

Answer (score 0):

A successful `ionic start` should look like below:

[image]

Looks like for some reason this command doesn't complete on your machine. Not sure what goes wrong for you, but as an alternative to `ionic start`, you can try downloading the starter project yourself through github. Just install `git`, and then type:

```
git clone https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-starter-sidemenu.git
```

Comment: will try and getback

Comment: it's downloaded, and i tried to run command npm install but it says no such file or directory package.json, and then nothing happens. is there any more steps involved,?

Comment: Is there any other files there? If you don't see any files in that folder, that means the `git clone` command was not successful. In that case your issue would not be an Ionic issue, but rather a `git` issue. I would make sure that I can clone any repo using git command first.

Comment: ,first i thank you very much for your sustained help. now git clone did downloaded files with folders like css , image, js , templates and index.html, manifest.json, readme.md finally service-worker.js.